# Java EE: Eclipselink transaction missing

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have a maven based Java EE project that should run on GlassFish v3. There is a JSF ManagedBean that injects an EJB service. ManagedBean calls one of the injected EJB's method on button click where some JPA operation happens (creation of new entity object, persisting, flushing). When the `EntityManager.flush()` called then it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException:  Exception
Description: No transaction is currently active
```

The data source is a jta data source with JTA transaction type (defined in persistence.xml).

I've already found a solution, but it is not satisfying due to deployment issues.
If I put the next line of code into the persistence.xml then it runs without any problem:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>
```

Because of this reason, I assume that it is a deployment problem, when the eclipselink does not recognize the JTA manager.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank You!

**UPDATE:**

@MRalwasser: here is the full stack trace. (sorry, i had to remove the real package names, it is masked.package.name now) [stack trace on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FD4XHAhG)

@Chris: sorry i forgot to mention, that the GeneriDao class creates the entity manager via the factory method, NOT by dependency injection.

Comment: can you show the exception's full stacktrace to us?

Comment: Unless the container is managing the persistence units so that it injects needed properties into the context, EclipseLink needs to be told how to look up the JTA transaction manager and data sources if specific to a server.  Ie if using javax.persistence.Persistence.getEntityManagerFactory instead of injection

Comment: Why can't you use `eclipselink.target-server`? Either in persistence.xml or overriding at initilization time, through properties. Without that property I met all kinds of classloader problems, including inactive transactions.

Answer (score 1):

The persistence control mechanisms of Java Enterprise have several options and specific design choices. In almost any Java EE implementation I worked with, comtainer managed transactions (CMT) were used. In an occastional situation, bean managed transactions (BMT) can be the choice.

**Bean managed transactions** can be preferred when you need to be sure, exactly when the 'commit' (or 'rollback') takes place during program execution. This can be required in a high-performing time-critical application area. For an example of BMT, see e.g. the section 'Bean Managed Transactions' in [examples, Bean Managed Transactions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_transactions.htm)

**Container managed transactions** means that the software in the application server ( 'the container') calls a 'begin' transction before Java code is executed that makes use of a persistence context. When the code execution is finisned (when the call tree has returned, e.g. as a result of a web-request), the application server calls 'commit'. Consequently, the modified entities are actually updated in the application database.

In Java EE, the statements: `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)` and `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` indicate container managed transactions, or bean managed transactions, respectively. Java EE 
defines several types of beans: session-driven bean, message-driven bean, local bean. These beans are generally `@Stateless`, and can all work with container managed transactions.

Detailed control of container managed transaction handling can in EE be specified by adding the annotations:

```
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW) 
public void myTopLevelMethodWhichStartsNewInnerTransaction()
....
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
public void myTopLevelMethodContinueExistingTransactionIfAny()
....
@TransactionAttribute(NEVER)
public void myNoCurrentTransactionAllowedWhenMethodCalled()
....
```

*Flush*

The necessarity of calling 'flush' to ensure that the database cache is written on disk, depends on the type of database used. E.g. for Postgress calling `flush` makes a difference, whereas for the in-memory database 'derby', flush has no effect, and can in that latter situation cause an error similar to the one reported in this question. The effect of `flush` is thus database dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Only EJB can working in CMT by default. In Managed beans or CDI beans you have to implement your own mechanism for handling transactions and run your service from within it.

```
public class ManagedBean {        

    @Inject
    yourEjbService service;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

    public void save(){
        try{
            utx.begin();
            service.doAction();
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ...
            } 
        }
    }
    ...
 }
```

You also don't have to call `EntityManager.flush()` neither in your EJB nor in managed bean if you are injecting EntityManager using `@PersistenceContext`. It will detach entities automatically after each method in your EJB ends.